# Ubuntu 22.04.4 getting freezed after resuming from Suspended

Tags: drivers, dell, freeze, bios, firmware

I have a Dell Latitude 5500, it works perfectly fine with Windows. But on installing Ubuntu, it started freezing unexpectedly. A common pattern I observed is on resuming it from the Suspended state. I've updated the BIOS and Firmware drivers by [Official drivers of Latitude 5500](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-pk/product-support/servicetag/0-UmdhQXlGQVZUZlJMNlZYUGV2ZWU4Zz090/drivers) while following [these steps](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-pk/000131486/update-the-dell-bios-in-a-linux-or-ubuntu-environment#Creating%20a%20USB%20Bootable%20Storage%20Device). After installing Ubuntu, I've installed all the required drivers by using the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

But still, I'm facing the same issues. The laptop specs and the logs are attached below.

Laptop Specs:

```
Processor: Intel Core i7-8665U CPU @ 1.9GHz x 8
Graphics: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2)
Memory: 32 GB
SSD: 512 GB ADATA LEGEND 710
```

Logs before Suspending (7:48:36 AM) and after Resuming from Suspended State (8:01:14 AM) until got freeze (8:01:19 AM):

```
 8:01:19 AM kernel: wlo1: associated
 8:01:15 AM kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno2: NIC Link is Down
 8:01:15 AM kernel: PM: suspend exit
 8:01:14 AM kernel: thermal thermal_zone7: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
 8:01:14 AM kernel: random: crng reseeded on system resumption
 8:01:14 AM kernel: done.
 8:01:14 AM kernel: mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_ops [i915])
 8:01:14 AM kernel: Restarting tasks ... 
 8:01:14 AM kernel: OOM killer enabled.
 8:01:14 AM kernel: ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
 8:01:14 AM kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
 8:01:14 AM kernel: intel_pch_thermal 0000:00:12.0: Wakeup event detected, abort cooling
 8:01:14 AM kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
 8:01:14 AM kernel: e1000e: EEE TX LPI TIMER: 00000011
 8:01:14 AM kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
 8:01:14 AM kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks completed (elapsed 0.001 seconds)
 8:01:14 AM kernel: OOM killer disabled.
 8:01:14 AM kernel: Freezing user space processes completed (elapsed 0.002 seconds)
 7:48:36 AM kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.024 seconds
 7:48:36 AM kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
 7:48:35 AM kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0xc0400707
 7:48:35 AM kernel: wlo1: deauthenticating from 10:10:81:84:c4:d8 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
 7:47:42 AM kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1710384462.333:102): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.snapd-desktop-integration" pid=6214 comm="apparmor_parser"
 7:47:40 AM kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 7 callbacks suppressed
 7:47:39 AM kernel: loop13: detected capacity change from 0 to 8
```

Comment: Ae [these instructions](https://linuxstoney.com/how-to-install-mesa-drivers-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts/) for installing MESA drivers helpful?